# How to draw a triangle by two(or three) given angles and a side(a line) with angles written at each corners in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, geometry, actionscript-2

I want to draw a triangle using two angles and a side length(or a just a straight line).Can anyone give me a code for ActionScript.Also each corner there should be the angle of that corner. Thanks in advance

Sorry i cannot upload any images..

just imagine a normal triangle named ABC.
i want to draw triangle by giving length of AB, and angles of A,B   .for example if i give corner "a=45 degree" and "b=45 degree" (then other angle will be 90 degrees) and "AB=20 pixels" then the triangle should be drawn.

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question a bit to make it clearer ? From what I gather it's a matter of using a [trigonometric functions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html)(sin/cos/tan mainly). What is the relationship between the two angles and the side ? Can you draw a diagram ?

Comment: http://cnx.org/content/m31227/1.1/Picture%203.png

like in this picture..if i give length of a = 20, angle of B=60 , angle of D=60 then is it possible to draw a triangle..

Comment: [Law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines): **a/sinA=b/sinB=c/sinC** ,you can get all sides length and angles.

Comment: Thanks .i know from maths , it is possible to draw them..I just dont know how to code it from actionscript..Can anyone please provide some codes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun with maths :)

The [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) class has a [graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#graphics) property which lets you draw with the Flash [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) API. To do basic line drawings, think of the tip of a pen. You can move the tip to an x,y coordinate, and draw lines to other coordinates. When you do that, the pen's tip now rests at the new coordinates. In Flash the coordinate plane's origin (0,0) is at the top/left.

I drew the triangle by setting the start coordinates with the `moveTo()` method. Then calculated the end points of the two lines that would be drawn from the starting coordinates. And finally, draw the line segments w/the `lineTo()` method.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

    public class DrawTriangle extends Sprite
    {
        private var startX:Number = 200;
        private var startY:Number = 200;

        private var angleA:Number = 10;
        private var angleB:Number = 90;
        private var lengthOfSideC:Number = 200;

        public function DrawTriangle()
        {
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            var angleAInRadians:Number = angleInRaidans(angleA);
            var angleBInRadians:Number = angleInRaidans(angleB);
            var angleCInRadians:Number = angleInRaidans(180 - angleA - angleB);
            var lengthOfSideA:Number = Math.sin(angleAInRadians) * lengthOfSideC / Math.sin(angleCInRadians);
            var lengthOfSideB:Number = Math.sin(angleBInRadians) * lengthOfSideC / Math.sin(angleCInRadians);

            var g:Graphics = this.graphics;
            g.clear();
            g.lineStyle(1.5, 0xFF0000, 1, true);
            g.moveTo(startX, startY);

            var bSideEndX:Number = (lengthOfSideB * Math.cos(angleBInRadians))+ startX;
            var bSideEndY:Number = (lengthOfSideB * Math.sin(angleBInRadians))+ startY;
            g.lineTo(bSideEndX, bSideEndY);

            g.lineStyle(1.5, 0x0000FF);
            var cSideEndX:Number = -(lengthOfSideC * Math.cos(angleCInRadians)) + startX;
            var cSideEndY:Number = (lengthOfSideC * Math.sin(angleCInRadians)) + startY;
            g.lineTo(cSideEndX, cSideEndY);

            g.lineStyle(1.5, 0);
            g.lineTo(startX, startY);
        }

        private function angleInRaidans(degrees:Number):Number
        {
            return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i ask one more thing ..how to rotate this triangle with specified angle.?? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2259502/398606) You can use that algorithm to get the new x/y values for the points defined by `(bSideEndX, bSideEndY)` and `(cSideEndX, cSideEndY)`. You are rotating those points around the starting point `(startX, startY)`.