# How to use x-y corrdinates and a radius to simulate a uniform circular orbit in c#?

Tags: c#

I have the orbit center point in x-y cords and radius between the center point and the orbiting point, along with the x-y cords of the orbiting. I need to update the orbiting points x-y cords so that it orbits the center point in a perfect circle. How can I do this? I have been stuck on it all day ...

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly you want to rotate a point around a other

```
Point center;
int radius;
double angle; // in radians
// get the Vektor from center to orbit
Point orbit = center + new Point(cos(angle)*radius, sin(angle)*radius)
```

You can use the trigonometric functions sinus and cosinus to calculate the x and y position of a circle with radius 1.
Then you multiply ith with your radius to get a citcle rith the radius `radius`.
At last you shift the coordinates by your center point so the rotation is not centered by (0|0). (Now its centered around your `center`)

See [here](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/2drota.htm) for mor information, or perhaps also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259476/rotating-a-point-about-another-point-2d) (its C++, but teh problem is nearly the same)

Comment: How do I use the vector structure? I tried using the vector structure but the keyword isn't working. On msdn it says it is in System.Windows; which I have already included..

Comment: You could either just define for yourself a class/struct Point (or Vektor - name it whatever you want :) ).
Or you can just use double centerX, centerY. And remeber through the hole programm x and y seperately