# Rotating a RigidBody around a pivot point

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

I'm trying to rotate a rigidbody around a pivot point (in this case the origin), rather than its center of mass.

I had a suggestion to apply three transformations:

1. Transform the rigidbody to the origin
2. Rotate the rigidbody on its center of mass
3. Transform the rigidbody off of the origin.

Here is my code:

```
btMatrix3x3 orn = btPhys->getWorldTransform().getBasis();   
btQuaternion quat;
orn.getRotation(quat);
btVector3 axis = quat.getAxis();

//Move rigidbody 2 units along its axis to the origin
btPhys->translate(btVector3(-2.0 * axis.getX(), 0.0, -2.0 * axis.getZ()));

//Rotate the rigidbody by 1 degree on its center of mass
orn *= btMatrix3x3(btQuaternion( btVector3(1, 0, 0), btScalar(degreesToRads(-1))));
btPhys->getWorldTransform().setBasis(orn);  

//Update axis variable to apply transform on
orn.getRotation(quat);
axis = quat.getAxis();

//Move the rigidbody 2 units along new axis
btPhys->translate(btVector3(2.0 * axis.getX(), 0.0, 2.0 * axis.getZ()));
```

However, the pivot points appears to be moving around instead of staying in one place (the origin). Is there a better way (that actually works) to rotate a rigidbody around a pivot point?

**EDIT:**
I added some sanity-check code for the rotate function:

```
//Code that doesn't work
btVector3 invTrans = btPhys->offsetToPivot.rotate(btVector3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), btScalar(degreesToRads(-1)));
//Values printed out are identical to offsetToPivot
printf("invTrans: %f %f %f\n", invTrans.getX(), invTrans.getY(), invTrans.getZ());

//Sanity code that DOES work
//Arbitrary vector
btVector3 temp = btVector3(0.0, 2.0, 0.0);
temp = temp.rotate(btVector3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), btScalar(degreesToRads(-1)));
printf("temp %f %f %f\n", temp.getX(), temp.getY(), temp.getZ());
```

Comment: You should transform the pivot point to the origin, then rotate, then apply the reverse transform.

Comment: I've eddited my answer.

Comment: For me both fragments of code work exactly the same assuming that offsetToPivot was initially set to `btVector3(0.0, 2.0, 0.0)`. If it was set to `btVector3(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0);` it obvously wont work, because you try to rotate point around the axis on which it lies, which of course leaves it in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method actually works, you're just applying it incorrectly. Your second translation is performed along world axis but you have rotated the object, so you have to translate it back along the rotated vector.

Correct code should look more or less like this:

```
btMatrix3x3 orn = btPhys->getWorldTransform().getBasis();   
btQuaternion quat;
orn.getRotation(quat);
btVector3 axis = quat.getAxis();

//Move rigidbody 2 units along its axis to the origin
btPhys->translate(btVector3(-2.0 * axis.getX(), 0.0, -2.0 * axis.getZ()));

//Rotate the rigidbody by 1 degree on its center of mass
orn *= btMatrix3x3(btQuaternion( btVector3(1, 0, 0), btScalar(degreesToRads(-1))));
btPhys->getWorldTransform().setBasis(orn);  

//Get rotation matrix
btTransform invRot(btQuaternion(btVector3(1, 0, 0), btScalar(degreesToRads(-1))),btVector3(0,0,0));
//Rotate your first translation vector with the matrix
btVector3 invTrans(-2.0 * axis.getX(), 0.0, -2.0 * axis.getZ());
invTrans = invRot * invTrans;

//Update axis variable to apply transform on
orn.getRotation(quat);
axis = quat.getAxis();

//Translate back by rotated vector
btPhys->translate(-invTrans);
```

I'm not sure if the rotation shouldn't be with minus (I can't check it right now) but you can easily try both.

EDIT.

Ok, so you forgot to mention that you perform a continuous rotation instead of a single one. This procedure is correct for a single rotation around pivot (eg. 30 degrees rotation). I've looked into your code once more and I understand that you try to perform your first translation along local x and z-axis. However it is not what happens. In this line:

```
btVector3 axis = quat.getAxis();
```

the variable axis is a unit vector representing the axis around which your object is rotated. It is NOT its coordinate system. I haven't noticed this part before. Quaternions are tricky and you should read more about them because many people missuse them.

A solution that will work in a continuous case is to store the last translation (from center of mass to pivot - in my example it is represented by invTrans) in your object and use it to perform the first translation, then rotate it in the same way it is done, and use it to move to the right position.

The corrected code will look like this:

```
btMatrix3x3 orn = btPhys->getWorldTransform().getBasis();   
btQuaternion quat;
orn.getRotation(quat);

//Move rigidbody 2 units along its axis to the origin
btPhys->translate(btPhys->offsetToPivot);

//Rotate the rigidbody by 1 degree on its center of mass
orn *= btMatrix3x3(btQuaternion( btVector3(1, 0, 0), btScalar(degreesToRads(-1))));
btPhys->getWorldTransform().setBasis(orn);  

//Get rotation matrix
btTransform invRot(btQuaternion(btVector3(1, 0, 0), btScalar(degreesToRads(-1))),btVector3(0,0,0));
//Rotate your first translation vector with the matrix
btVector3 invTrans = invRot * btPhys->offsetToPivot;

//Update axis variable to apply transform on
orn.getRotation(quat);
axis = quat.getAxis();

//Translate back by rotated vector
btPhys->translate(-invTrans); 
btPhys->offsetToPivot = invTrans;
```

However before starting this whole procedure you have to set offsetToPivot into its position relative to the center of mass.

I have an impression that the main source of your problems is the lack of understanding of linear algebra and basic spatial transformations. If you are planning to continue in this field, I strongly recommend reading into this topic. Also drawing your problem on paper really helps.

EDIT2.

Ok, I've tried your code:

```
btVector3 temp = vec3(0,2,0);
btTransform invRot(btQuaternion(btVector3(1, 0, 0), btScalar(-0.017453f)),btVector3(0,0,0));
temp = invRot * temp;
```

After this, `temp` is equal to `{0.000000000, 1.99969542, -0.0349042267}`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Shouldn't invRot be the same rotation that was applied to the rigidBody (there is a btVector3 now)? I tried using this code but it's causing the rigidbody to rotate on it's center of mass while moving up and down. Does the rigidbody have to have a height of 0 for this to work?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I understand what you're doing now, but I still don't think the code is quite right. I printed out invTrans and it appears to be the same as bt->offsetToPivot; so for some reason invRot didn't get applied properly.

Comment: @Jaitnium you know... I can't run this code anywhere so it is written from my mind and there is no way for me to check it. If you understand the approach, you can at least try to fix it on your own. In what line do you print those values? Do you see the line `btPhys->offsetToPivot = invTrans;`? After this line, they should be equal. What is the behavior of your RigidBody? What initial value did you assign to `offsetToPivot`? What is the initial `WorldTransform` when you start rotating? Have you tried using debugger as I advised you?

Comment: bt->offsetToPivot is the same as invTrans after the line: "btVector3 invTrans = invRot * btPhys->offsetToPivot;" The behaviour is that the rigidbody is still spinning on it's center of mass.

Comment: @Jaitnium And what is the initial value of `btPhys->offsetToPivot`? Do you even set it anywhere? And the position? How do you imagine anybody can help you if you don't provide crucial information? Actually I've checked this line and it definitely sets `invTrans` into other value than `offsetToPivot`. One more question... What does your function degreesToRads return?

Comment: @Jaitnium Can you post this code in your question. This way I can't read it at all...

Comment: I set btPhys->offset to btVector3(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0) prior to the loop. degreesToRads returns -0.017444 (or the actual code is : "   return (3.14f * degrees)/180.0f;"

Comment: @Jaitnium Please check my last edit. I have no idea why you don't obtain the same result... Something must be wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I figured out the problem! I was trying to rotate on the x axis instead of the y. The values weren't changing because I was trying to rotate the offsetToPivot vector (which is lying on the x-axis -2, 0, 0) with respect to the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

In the below function, these transformations perform the three steps you've described:

```
int x = cos(angRads) * (initial.x - axisOfRotation.x) - sin(angRads) * (initial.y - axisOfRotation.y) + axisOfRotation.x;      
int y = sin(angRads) * (initial.x - axisOfRotation.x) + cos(angRads) * (initial.y - axisOfRotation.y) + axisOfRotation.y;
```

namely:

> Step 1:Transform the rigidbody to the origin.

```
    initial.x - axisOfRotation.x
    initial.y - axisOfRotation.y
```

> Step 2:Rotate the rigidbody on its center of mass.

```
    cos(angRads) * initial.x - sin(angRads) * initial.y
    sin(angRads) * initial.x + cos(angRads) * initial.y
```

> Step 3:Transform the rigidbody off of the origin.

```
    +axisOfRotation.x;
    +axisOfRotation.y;
```

Here is a recursive function that performs exactly what you need and returns
all the consecutively rotated points in a vector: (use it as a benchmark)

```
rotateCoordinate(vector<Point>& rotated, Point& axisOfRotation, Point initial, 
                            float angRads, int numberOfRotations){
    // base case: when all rotations performed return vector holding the rotated points
    if(numberOfRotations <= 0) return;
    else{
        // apply transformation on the initial point
        int x = cos(angRads) * (initial.x - axisOfRotation.x) - sin(angRads) * (initial.y - axisOfRotation.y) + axisOfRotation.x;
        int y = sin(angRads) * (initial.x - axisOfRotation.x) + cos(angRads) * (initial.y - axisOfRotation.y) + axisOfRotation.y;
        // save the result
        rotated.push_back(Point(x, y));
        // call the same function this time on the rotated point and decremented number of rotations
        rotateCoordinate(rotated, axisOfRotation, Point(x,y), angRads, numberOfRotations -1);
    }
}
```

where `Point` is:

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
    Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) { }
    Point() :x(0), y(0) { }
};
```

For further reading that explains the math behind it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259476/rotating-a-point-about-another-point-2d/32376643#32376643).

Comment: So what's the point in using Bullet then? Btw. your transformation only works to rotate a `Point` in a 2D plane, while the question is to rotate a `Rigid Body` around the 3D axis. It is a little bit more complex than that. Even if you scale it to a 3D space (which is painful), you still calculate only the position of the body, but where is the orientation?

Comment: @Estiny you are right. I'll update the answer to match the question requirements, apologies!