# Rotate a point around another point using the angle returned by atan2()

Tags: javascript, math

I have a rotation angle:

```
var dx = this.mouseX - this.startX;
var dy = this.mouseY - this.startY;

_this.rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
```

And i know my pivot point (center of my image):

```
var pivotX = this.x + (this.imageWidth / 2);
var pivotY = this.y + (this.imageHeight / 2);
```

Now i have got another point:

```
var rightX = 600;
var rightY = 400;
```

How can i rotate this point around my pivot point using the angle that i got from the `atan2()` function?

Comment: Could you show your full code? Right now it is impossible to define the problem correctly and see what you are doing.

Comment: I thout its enough. I just need to calculate the new position of `rightX` and `rightY` using the rotation and the pivot point. I dont do more so i cant show more. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259476/rotating-a-point-about-another-point-2d but they are not working with atan2() and i have no idea about math. I guess i cant copy that.

Comment: Here what are the `this` and `_this` variables? When are you calling this code? I'm trying to get the whole picture of what you are doing.

Comment: Look at the answer Alvaro. What i do with it is not interesting. I only asked for rotating a point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To rotate a point {x, y} around an origin {0, 0} by a given angle in radians do the following math:

```
new_x_point = old_x_point * cos(Angle) - old_y_point * sin(Angle);
new_y_point = old_y_point * cos(Angle) + old_x_point * sin(Angle);
```

Now, if the origin or pivot point is not {0, 0}, then you will need to first subtract the point you want to rotate from the coordinates of the origin point, *then* do the rotation on that point, and then add the offset of the rotated point back in so that it's translated back to it's original position.