# How draw axis of ellipse

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using `fitellipse` of Opencv and C++, and I'm getting these values:

```
/// Find the rotated rectangles and ellipses for each contour
vector<RotatedRect> minRect( contours.size() );
vector<RotatedRect> minEllipse( contours.size() );

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
   minRect[i] = minAreaRect( Mat(contours[i]) );

   if( contours[i].size() > 5 )
      minEllipse[i] = fitEllipse( Mat(contours[i]) );

   // ...
}

float xc    = minEllipse[element].center.x;
float yc    = minEllipse[element].center.y;
float a     = minEllipse[element].size.width  / 2;   
float b     = minEllipse[element].size.height / 2;
float theta = minEllipse[element].angle;
```

But with these values how can I draw the axis of an ellipse, for example of the following ellipse?
[image]

NOTE: Element is an ellipse stored in `minEllipse`.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a line segment given its endpoint, length, and slope angle?

Comment: I want draw rotated axis of ellipse with point center of ellipse, length of radius, and angle, because the ellipse in image are rotated so I want draw the new axis inside ellipse.

Comment: It looks like you need help with geometry rather than programming.

Comment: I think that axis are posible to draw with only these values, but I search and I don't found, and all geometry methods that I used don't give me good results.

Comment: If you cannot draw it on paper, then you are at a wrong site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `minEllipse[element].points` to get the four corners of the rotated bounding rectangle, like described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html#details).

Then you only need to calculate the average of the two points on each side of the rectangle to get the endpoints for the axes...

```
Point2f vertices[4];
minEllipse[element].points(vertices);
line(image, (vertices[0] + vertices[1])/2, (vertices[2] + vertices[3])/2, Scalar(0,255,0));
line(image, (vertices[1] + vertices[2])/2, (vertices[3] + vertices[0])/2, Scalar(0,255,0));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for those formulas:

```
ct = cos(theta)
st = sin(theta)

LongAxix0.x = xc - a*ct
LongAxis0.y = yc - a*st
LongAxis1.x = xc + a*ct
LongAxix1.y = yc + a*st

ShortAxix0.x = xc - b*st
ShortAxix0.y = yc + b*ct
ShortAxis1.x = xc + b*st
ShortAxix2.y = yc - b*ct
```

Answer (score 0):

> But with these values how can I draw the axis of an ellipse?

The axis of the ellipse are passing through its centre:

```
float xc = minEllipse[element].center.x;
float yc = minEllipse[element].center.y;
```

the start and end points of the axis could be at an offset from the centre defined by the ellipse's width and height, i.e.:

```
// horizontal axis start/ end point

// coordinates
int HxStart = xc - size.width  / 2;
int HyStart = yc;

int HxEnd = xc + size.width  / 2;
int HyEnd = yc;

// points
Point Hstart(HxStart, HyStart);
Point Hend(HxEnd, HyEnd);

// horizontal axis
Line horizontalAxis(Hstart, Hend);

// vertical axis start/ end point
int VxStart = xc;
int VyStart = yc - size.height  / 2;

int VxEnd = xc;
int VyEnd = yc + size.height  / 2;

// ----//----
```

Now, you can [rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259476/rotating-a-point-about-another-point-2d/32376643#32376643) the axis (the above for points) by the provided angle `theta`, around the centre of the ellipse.

Having the above and knowing how to construct a line you can build the two axis at any given angle `theta`.