# Numpy rot90 for 2d points

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image and several 2D points `[(x, y), ...]`. I would like to rotate both the image and the points by 90 degrees.

For the image I can simply use `np.rot90`. For the points I figured I have to rotate them 90 degrees around the center of the image to make them align correctly (for this I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/58781388/2445065)

Original image (note: red point is not part of the image):

[image]

After rotating the image and the point:

[image]

Whereas I would expect the red dot to be at the bottom left corner of the yellow square... Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: redpoint->y = redpoint->y + rectangle->height ?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but that would only work when I know the rectangle height. In this case, I used the rectangle only for demonstration

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it:

To align the points and additional translation is require. `np.rot90` does not equal a translation around the center but rather a rotation around the center PLUS a translation such that the top left corner of the rotated image is located at `(0, 0)`.

You can get the translation by subtracting `|origin_rotated.x - origin_original.x|` from the x-coordinate and `|origin_rotated.y - origin_original.y|` from the y-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

This python function will do rot90 for points:

```
def rot90points(x, y, k, hw):
    """
        a = np.zeros((5, 12), dtype="uint8");
        x, y = np.array([2, 5, 7]), np.array([4, 4, 2])
        a[y, x] = 200;
        for k in range(10):  # test
            a1 = np.rot90(a, k);
            x1, y1 = rot90points(x, y, k, a.shape);
            assert np.all(a1[y1, x1] == 200)
    """
    k = k % 4
    if k == 0: return x, y
    elif k == 1: return y, hw[1] - 1 - x
    elif k == 2: return hw[1] - 1 - x, hw[0] - 1 - y
    elif k == 3: return hw[0] - 1 - y, x
    else: raise ValueError(f"k error {k}")
```