# Find 2 points based off how much a point has rotated around a center point

Tags: c++, math, rotation, trigonometry, 2d-vector

I am making a little game and I am now working on a "radar". Now to do this I need to find two points based off how much a point has rotated around a center point.

[image]

`A` is going to rotate around `C`.

As `A` rotates around `C`, `B` & `D` will move along with `A` and stay in the same "positions" based off of where `A` is.

So for example, if `A` rotates around `C` 90 degrees `B` & `D` would then move and be in this position

[image]

But I am not very good at trig, so I don't really know the math I would need in order to find `B` & `D` based off how much `A` has rotated around `C`.

How do i find `B` & `D` based off of how much `A` has rotated around `C`?

I would image the final math would look somewhat similar to this:

```
float * returnB(float * APoint, float * CPoint)
{
    float B_Out[2];
    //calculate where B is based off A & C
    B_Out[0] = B_X;
    B_Out[1] = B_Y;
    return B_Out;
}

float B[2];
B[0] = returnB(A,C)[0];
B[1] = returnB(A,C)[1];

float * returnD(float * APoint, float * CPoint)
{
    float D_Out[2];
    //calculate where D is based off A & C
    D_Out[0] = D_X;
    D_Out[1] = D_Y;
    return D_Out;
}

float D[2];
D[0] = returnD(A,C)[0];
D[1] = returnD(A,C)[1];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259476/rotating-a-point-about-another-point-2d

Comment: Do you know the angle by which A gets rotated around C?

Answer (score 4):

You can rotate a point `(x, y)` around the origin by performing a simple matrix multiplication, which gives the following equations for the transformed point `(x0, y0)`:

```
x0 = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
y0 = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you know A's relative 2d position respect to C. Lets say it is (ax, ay).

If you cross product(0,0,1) with (ax, ay, 0) you will find relative position of D that will be something like (dx, dy, 0)

d = (dx, dy) is relative position of D.
b is also -d

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product