# How to rotate a rectangle around an origin?

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, geometry

I'm trying to rotate two rectangles the same amount around the same point. The point is arbitrary, so for simplicity, I'm using the top-left `(0, 0)`

Unfortunately, the result seems slightly off, and I'm not sure what's causing it. Here is a full reproduction of the issue:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

class Rectangle {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, theta) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.theta = theta;
  }
}

function drawRectangle(r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(r.x, r.y, r.w, r.h);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function degreesToRadians(degrees) { return degrees * (Math.PI / 180); }

function rotateCanvas(radians, centerX, centerY) {
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
  ctx.rotate(radians);
  ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
}

function drawRotatedRectangle(r) {
  let rXCenter = r.x + (r.w / 2);
  let rYCenter = r.y + (r.h / 2);
  alert(rXCenter);

  rotateCanvas(r.theta, rXCenter, rYCenter);
  drawRectangle(r);
  rotateCanvas(-r.theta, rXCenter, rYCenter);
}

let r1 = new Rectangle(100, 52, 90, 30, degreesToRadians(-20));
let r2 = new Rectangle(140, 80, 25, 25, degreesToRadians(10));

function simpleRotate(r, theta) {
  let transX = Math.cos(theta) * r.x - Math.sin(theta) * r.y;
  let transY = Math.sin(theta) * r.x + Math.cos(theta) * r.y;

  return new Rectangle(transX, transY, r.w, r.h, r.theta + theta);
}

drawRotatedRectangle(r1);
drawRotatedRectangle(r2);

let r1AABB = simpleRotate(r1, -r1.theta);
let r2Rotate = simpleRotate(r2, -r1.theta);

ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
drawRotatedRectangle(r1AABB);
drawRotatedRectangle(r2Rotate);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

The black rectangles are the two rectangles before being rotated, and the red rectangles are the two rectangles after being rotated.

As you can see, the two black rectangles are touching (colliding) before being rotated. Then, I rotate them both by the same amount around the same point `(0, 0)`. However, afterwards they are no longer touching (as you can see the red rectangles are no longer colliding.

Why is this? I followed [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109215) for rotating a point, but I seem to be getting inaccurate results.

If I take a screenshot of the black rectangles, open it up an image editor, box select them, and rotate them, then they stay together (colliding). How can I emulate this in my code example posted above?

Comment: Emm... What is x (and y) for rotated rectangle?

Comment: @MBo I'm not sure what you mean? Which line of code are you referring to?

Comment: You define some basic point x,y in rectangle class. It has undoubted meaning in case of axis-aligned rectangles, but where is basic point for rotated ones? Perhaps rectangle center would be more reliable (common case  in comp. geometry for arbitrary rectangles - define center, and some variants for orientation - or side vectors, or width/height/angle)

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. Yeah, rotated rectangles are rotated around their origin (their center) when drawn.

Comment: I was in doubts seeing `let rXCenter = r.x + (r.w / 2);` If rectangle is rotated - where is center calculated by this formula?

Comment: Well, doesn't Javascript let you draw a rotated rectangle by rotating the canvas, drawing the rectangle normally, and then rotating the canvas back? That's what I'm doing in the snippet above.

Comment: You rotate canvas about rectangle center. And I am not sure where is this center for rotated rect ( `r1AABB = simpleRotate` then `drawRotatedRectangle(r1AABB);` ) Perhaps my doubts are wrong, I don't know JS  enough.

Comment: Well, the only real Javascript that you have to know for this is the `rotateCanvas` function. All that does is just rotates the entire canvas by `radians` at a given point. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate So I rotate the canvas by theta, draw a rectangle, and then rotate the canvas back to normal. This is how I draw a rotated rectangle.

Comment: But I do think you're right in that it may be something wrong with that function.. because if I change `rXCenter` to equal `r.x`, then they no longer become separated after rotating.. But I don't want those rectangles to rotate around their top-left point, and instead to rotate around their center.

Comment: I added `alert(rXCenter);` in `drawRotatedRectangle` function and see distinct values. So rotations occur about different centers

Comment: Yeah I see that now too.. but I'm still not exactly sure how to fix it.. Should `rXCenter` do some sort of sin or cosine multiplication to get their rotated center points or something?

Comment: The problem is with the center of the rotation canvas, which should be the center of the rotated rectangle. But you use the center of the unrotated rectangle !

Answer (score 1):

This may let it work as you expect.

```
function simpleRotate(r, theta) {
    let transX = Math.cos(theta) * (r.x + r.w / 2) - Math.sin(theta) * (r.y + r.h / 2) - r.w / 2;
    let transY = Math.sin(theta) * (r.x + r.w / 2) + Math.cos(theta) * (r.y + r.h / 2) - r.h / 2;
    return new Rectangle(transX, transY, r.w, r.h, r.theta + theta);
}
```

Other otherwise, if you'd like to change center, use following form.

```
function simpleRotate(r, theta, centerX, centerY) {
    let transX = Math.cos(theta) * (r.x + r.w / 2 - centerX) - Math.sin(theta) * (r.y + r.h / 2 - centerY) - r.w / 2 + centerX;
    let transY = Math.sin(theta) * (r.x + r.w / 2 - centerX) + Math.cos(theta) * (r.y + r.h / 2 - centerY) - r.h / 2 + centerY;
    return new Rectangle(transX, transY, r.w, r.h, r.theta + theta);
}
```

Then

```
let r1AABB = simpleRotate(r1, -r1.theta, 145, 67);
let r2Rotate = simpleRotate(r2, -r1.theta, 145, 67);
```

#### How these work

In general, `2d rotational transform with offset` consists of `translation` and `rotation`. Then, in that setup `rotation` is to be applied via `drawRotatedRectangle()` afterwards. Therefore all what you have to do is to compose appropriate `translation`. Inspecting `simpleRotate()` function carefully, you'll notice what's actually done there is calculation of `translation` (`transX`, `transY` ... though `sin`/`cos` are being used).

Then, as you know, since `drawRotatedRectangle()` rotates the rectangle around its center, by composing `translation` to move the center to the appropriate position, you can obtain `rotational transform` you need.

[image]

Initial state → Translate each item by simpleRotate() → Rotate each item by drawRotatedRectangle() → Final state.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, but this doesn't seem to fix it either. Also, don't I want to not rotate the center point of the rectangle (which this seems to do)? My intuition is that I need to only get the new x and y positions for the top left of the rectangle.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what your goal is like. To my understandings, your rotateCanvas() function seems to support only separated rotation of each rectangle around its center. If you'd like to rotate multiple rectangle in some synchronize manners by your implementation, it's not suitable for your purpose. However, there would be a way. Please provide brief sketch of rectangle arrangements you expect, if possible.

Comment: Sure, here is a rough sketch I just made in MS Paint: https://i.imgur.com/UqHOQPf.png The left is what I currently have, but the right is what I'm shooting for. Basically to have both shapes rotate around the top left (0, 0) together.

Comment: Seeing the sketch, I think the code in my answer is not so wrong. Please try it first by yourself. Then let's consider what's wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I think I am messing something up on my end. I'll continue experimenting with your code here.

Comment: @Ryan Peschel I re-read question and now  I don't sure, about what point you want to rotate ;) Formula from your link is correct.

Comment: Very sorry, there was an error in the expression. `transX`'s `r.y + r.w/2` should have been `r.y + r.h/2`. This was already fixed. And I appended some brief explanations, read it too. thank you.

Comment: Yes! my app can finally rotate videos!